# Clip-path/web-kit-mask works when SVG is seperate file, but not when inline

Tags: javascript, css, svg, clipping, css-mask

I am using the following implementation to mask an element using an SVG and some CSS.

```
//styles.css
.elementToBeMasked {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip-path:url(rhombus.svg#rhombusclip); 
    -webkit-mask:url(rhombus.svg#rhombus); 
    -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
} ...

//rhombus.svg
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="500" height="500">
  <clipPath id="rhombusclip">
    <path id="rhombuspath" d="M0,0 L500,0 500,500 100,500 z" fill="#000000" />
  </clipPath>
  <path id="rhombus" d="M0,0 L500,0 500,500 100,500 z" fill="#000000" />
</svg>
```

This works fine across Chrome, Safari and Firefox. However, I'm hoping to animate some of the properties, and so I've been trying to bring the SVG inline into my HTML.

This is my inline SVG code:

```
//index.html
<div class="elementToBeMasked">...</div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="500" height="500">
    <clipPath id="rhombusclip">
      <path id="rhombuspath" d="M0,0 L500,0 500,500 100,500 z" fill="#000000" />
    </clipPath>
    <path id="rhombus" d="M0,0 L500,0 500,500 100,500 z" fill="#000000" />
</svg>
```

And this is my updated CSS:

```
 //styles.css
 .elementToBeMasked {
     ...
     clip-path:url(index.html#rhombusclip); 
     -webkit-mask:url(index.html#rhombus);
 }
```

*This* implementation doesn't work across any browser. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to use `clip-path` and `mask` (or `-webkit-mask`) at the same time. They may appear to do the same thing, but they're separate properties. Have you tried using `clip-path` and `-webkit-clip-path` instead? then at least you're using "the same" property.

Answer (score 1):

If you write `#rhombusclip` in `styles.css` that's actually a shorthand for `styles.css#rhombusclip` and as there's not `#rhombusclip` in the `styles.css` file the lookup fails.

You'll need to write `index.html#rhombusclip` instead and do the same for other references too.

This is what the w3c CSS standard says and all UAs that I know of except for Webkit work like this. I imagine Webkit will change at some point since it is the odd one out.

Comment: Thanks for that - it doesn't seem to have fixed it, but that was no-doubt also a problem.

Comment: Having had more time to test this it doesn't appear to work. Putting the styles inline as well and just using the identifier does seem to work.

Comment: I apologize Robert, I have downvoted you but after hours of testing my specific usecase which generates an inverted mask for rect elements, I realized you were actually right, but I can no longer change the downvote.

Comment: I edited my answer so you can revote now if you want. Entirely up to you though :-)

Answer (score 0):

Quick update, the following seems to work inline but only in Firefox.

```
        <style>
        .box {
            position: fixed; 
            width: 450px; 
            height: 320px; 
            top: 10%; 
            left: 10%; 
            clip-path:url(#rhombusclip); 
            -webkit-mask:url(#rhombus); 
            -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
        }
        </style>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <svg width="1000" height="1000">
            <defs>
                <clipPath id="rhombusclip">
                    <path d="M0,0 L500,0 500,500 100,500 z" fill="#000000" />
                </clipPath>
                <path id="rhombus" d="M0,0 L500,0 500,500 100,500 z" fill="#000000" />
            </defs>
        </svg>
```